# Only one of our servers throws error of method not conforming to the required signature

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ienumerable

I am trying to upload a Silverlight project built in MVVM,using EntityFramework and WCF RIA, to a certain testing server that should be the exact copy of another server we are already actively using. However, this one doesn't accept `IEnumerable` as arguments to the method,throwing this error:

WebHost failed to process a request.
Sender Information:

```
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/23034936
Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/Hub/Services/NewWay-Branch-Ria-Web-Services-HoldMailService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Operation named 'MakePrintLog' does not conform to the required signature. Parameter types must be an entity or complex type, a collection of complex types, or one of the predefined serializable types.. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation named 'MakePrintLog' does not conform to the required signature. Parameter types must be an entity or complex type, a collection of complex types, or one of the predefined serializable types.
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainServiceDescription.ValidateMethodSignature(DomainServiceDescription description, DomainOperationEntry method)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainServiceDescription.AddInvokeOperation(DomainOperationEntry method)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainServiceDescription.Initialize()
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainServiceDescription.CreateDescription(Type domainServiceType)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainServiceDescription.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetDescription>b__f(Type type)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainServiceDescription.GetDescription(Type domainServiceType)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHost..ctor(Type domainServiceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
```

Here is the method in class HoldMailDbWorker, on server side:

```
public static void MakePrintLog(IEnumerable<HoldMailDetailsEntity> details_list, string branch, DateTime printed_at, string printed_by)
{ 
    try
    { 
        using (OracleConnection conn = DatabaseConnect.GetOracleConnection())
        {
            conn.Open();

            foreach (var detail in details_list)
            {
                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("CREATE_PRINT_LOG", conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("P_ID", OracleDbType.Varchar2, detail.Id.ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("P_BRANCH", OracleDbType.Varchar2, branch, ParameterDirection.Input);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("P_PRINTED_AT", OracleDbType.Date, printed_at, ParameterDirection.Input);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("P_PRINTED_BY", OracleDbType.Varchar2, printed_by, ParameterDirection.Input);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("P_UPLOAD_DATE", OracleDbType.Date, detail.UploadDate, ParameterDirection.Input);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error when creating print logs: " + exc.Message);
    }
}
```

And this method is calling it from class `HoldMailService` that is mentioned in the error:

```
[Invoke]
public void MakePrintLog(IEnumerable<HoldMailDetailsEntity> details_list, string branch, DateTime printed_at, string printed_by)
{
    HoldMailDbWorker.MakePrintLog(details_list, branch, printed_at, printed_by);
}
```

It has no compilation errors when testing directly from Visual Studio and previous version of the project that also contain the mentioned kind of method signature are successfully running on other servers.

I have searched through already asked questions about this kind of error but none are related to error being thrown on server side only. I thought maybe it could be missing WCF RIA Services SP1 because someone mentioned it in a similar question ,but it is there..

So our conclusion is that it must be some installation missing from this server, but we might be wrong.

Does anyone have some ideas that could help?

Comment: I would publish the application and the install using the setup.exe folder built with the publish.  Choose the build to CD but you can put on any file system.  The most likely reason for the error is the server is missing or has a different version of a window dll.   The publish will update the dll so it will run.

Comment: Compare the machine .config files on both servers and look for differences. That might help.